# Does GeForce 525M support Stable Diffusion web UI and ComfyUI?

Tags: software-installation, gpu, nvidia-geforce, v-ram

Error.install st . The problem was that your graphics card, GeForce GT 525M, has the Fermi architecture, which does not support Stable Diffusion.

Does GeForce 525M support Stable Diffusion web UI and ComfyUI GUI for Stable Diffusion or even in Google Colab?

Comment: ehm the body does not make sense. and what is cnfyui? and afaik you need an RX for it so I'd say: no it does not

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is the specification of my system, I want to know how can I use stable fusion on this system, is it possible or not because I know that my system is old.                     ...........                              .Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2410M CPU @ 2.30GHz 2.30 Ram :4.00 GB Intel(R) HD Graphics 3000 NVIDIA GeForce GT 525M

Answer (score 0):

Your GeForce GT 525M mobile graphics chip graphics processing unit does not support Stable Diffusion. The GeForce GT 525M mobile graphics chip was launched in 2011. It's too old for this GPU-intensive application.

While the GPU is crucial, a decent CPU (preferably 8 cores or more) also contributes to Stable Diffusion's overall performance. In addition 16GB or more of RAM is recommended for all scenarios, especially ComfyUI and Google Colab.

Recommended graphics processor requirements for Stable Diffusion scenarios:

1. Stable Diffusion web UI:

   - Minimum: Any GPU with at least 4GB of VRAM (video RAM).
   - Recommended: 6GB or more of VRAM for smoother experience.
2. ComfyUI node-based GUI for Stable Diffusion:

   - Minimum: 8GB of VRAM recommended, especially for higher resolutions or inpainting features.
   - Recommended: 12GB or more of VRAM for comfortable usage with larger image sizes, multiple prompts, and advanced settings.
   - Note: ComfyUI utilizes your local hardware, so performance is directly tied to your own GPU capabilities.
3. Stable Diffusion in Google Colab:

   - Minimum: A Colab Pro or Plus subscription to access dedicated GPUs.
   - Recommended: Choose GPUs with 16GB or more of VRAM for faster generation and larger images.

Comment: Does it mean that it is definitely not possible in any of the two ways?
/ stable diffusion comfyui
  and
   stable diffusion webui /

Even ... google colab

Thank

Comment: @AliFakhimi I posted a detailed reply to your comment in the answer. Thanks for providing the extra information.